# 「XY 問題」とは何ですか？

Tags: 討議, よくある質問, 質問の仕方, 専門用語

「XY 問題」とは何ですか？

質問する際、XY 問題に陥っていないか知る方法はありませんか？　どうしたら避けられるのでしょうか？

<sub>(この投稿は、community wiki による Stack Exchange Meta への投稿 ["What is the XY problem?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/341401) の和訳です。)</sub>

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### XY 問題とは？

[XY 問題](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)とは、自分が直面している **実際の問題** ではなく、自分で考えた **解決法** について質問してしまうことです。

つまり、ある問題 `X` に困っていて、ある解決法 `Y` で上手くいきそうだと考えた結果、`Y` についてのみ質問することを指します。自分が実際に困っている `X` についての説明は無いため、あなたの質問を読んだ方は `X` について知らない状態になってしまいます。

### 何が問題？

このような質問の仕方をすると、あなたの質問を解決してくれようとした方と上手くやり取りできないことがあります。なぜなら、あなたが投稿した質問とあなたが本当に解決したかった問題とには、全く関連が無いかもしれないからです。

### だから、こうしましょう

XY 問題に陥らないためには、今まで試してみた方法たちを全部書き、より広い視点で質問するようにしてください。

詳細を求められたときはそれを追記してください。特に、より具体的な話を求められれば可能な限り答えるようにしましょう。

もし既に試してみて駄目だったと思った解決法があるなら、それを試してみて駄目だったことも書いておきましょう。その部分についてのやり取りを繰り返さずに済みます。

このようにすることで、実際に悩んでいる問題についての情報が豊富になり、より良い回答が集まりやすくなります。

### 例

ひとつの例として、IRC での会話を見てみましょう。

> **Q**: ふたつのデリミタで囲まれた部分の文字列を返す関数はありませんか？
>
> **B**: どういうことですか？　多分そういう関数があるとは思いますが……
>
> **C**: split して slice すれば良い
>
> **D**: partition でも OK
>
> **Q**: partition は試しました
> **Q**: 組み込み関数を使って、文字列中の "attribute1: 50.223, attribute2: 442.1" みたいなところから数を取り出そうとしてたんです
>
> **D**: 単にその文字列をパーズすれば良いのでは？
>
> **Q**: パーズするような関数が組み込みであるかも、と思ったんです
>
> **D**: pairs = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]; attribs = {k: v for x in pairs for k, v in [x.split(": ")]}
> **D**: ライブラリの関数はあまり充実してないけど、これには単純な format 関数があれば充分ですね。あ、エラー処理は別で必要です
> **D**: データを json とか yaml とかの有名なフォーマットにできるなら、その方が良いです
>
> **Q**: このコードは HTML から取ってきてるんです
> **Q**: でも HTMLParser とか何かしらを使って Javascript をパーズするやり方が分からなくて
>
> **D**: html に埋め込まれてそうなデータには見えないですね。あるいは何かしら mangle された html でしょうか？
>
> **Q**: HTML に埋め込まれてました
>
> **D**: もし javascript のことを言っているなら（外側を { } で囲えばそうなります）、たぶん json でパーズできますよ
>
> **Q**: ありがとうございます
>
> **D**: ちゃんと言うと、json はデータをパーズします。js のコードはパーズできません
>
> **Q**: そう、データをパーズしたかったんです

上のやり取りで質問者が解決したかった本当の問題は JavaScript 中のデータをパーズすることであり、「ふたつのデリミタで囲まれた部分の文字列」を見つけることではありません。しかし真の問題へ至るまでには時間がかかってしまいました。

こういう会話は、チャットでならある程度簡単にできますが、Stack Exchange のサイトではそうはいきません。書いたものを推敲して投稿し、返信が返ってくるまで 5～30 分、あるいはもっとかかるこのサイトにおいては、解決すべき問題が最初からはっきりしていると、本当に助かるのです。

---

<sub>(この回答は、community wiki による[こちらの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/341401)を和訳した後、編集されたものです。)</sub>