# SO日本語版は回答者の自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たすためのサイトなのでしょうか？

Tags: 討議

タイトルのとおりです。
そうでなければ、その際に気をつけるべき点をご回答ください。

Comment: 念のためお聞きしますが、このメタ質問は dameo さんの最近の質問がクローズされている事と関係有りますか？

Comment: 関係あるかないかを問うこと自体が本質問の内容に無関係ですよ。

Comment: こちらの討議はある種の[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)に陥っているかもしれません。少なくとも自分は、こちらのご質問の意図するところがよく分かりませんでした。何かしら具体的な問題が他にあって、その対処に悩んでらっしゃったりしませんか。何かお困りのことがあるのであればそのことにも触れていただけると、より目的に沿った回答ができるかもしれません。また、今のままだとやや宙に浮いた議論になってしまわないかと危惧しています。

Comment: 何言ってるのか分かりませんよ。メタサイトでそんなメタなこと言わないで具体的に指摘してください。

Comment: あれあれ？また指摘もできない人がマイナス評価だけ入れて逃げていきましたね
マイナス評価はあなたの不満を解消するためのものではありませんよ

Comment: @dameo 煽るような言動は避けていただけますか。[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)の「けなす言動や敵意のある言葉は許されません」や「嫌がらせは許されません」です。「マイナス票を入れるのであれば改善点を議論してほしい」というご意見自体は有り得るものなのに、言い方のせいでコメントの削除を検討せねばならなくなっています……。

Comment: メタな議論ではある程度分かりやすく書いたほうがいいですよ。煽ってるわけではありません。私はメタじゃない方で散々煽られてますがｗもちろん誰もお咎め受けてませんけどね。

Comment: @dameo 本題とは関係ありませんが一応書いておくと、dameo さんのコメントへの通報を受けてモデレーターとして処理したこともあれば、他の方が dameo さんに宛てたコメントが通報されて処理したこともあります。行動規範にも書かれているように、書いた本人に煽る意図があったかどうかではなく、書かれた文言がどう受け取られるかが問題になります。インターネット越しに行うテキストでのコミュニケーションでは細かいニュアンスが伝わりづらいものです。書き方をなるべくフレンドリーな側に倒していただけると助かります。

Comment: じゃあ、通報した人とモデレータ自身の判断が不適切なのだと思いますよ。ニュアンスが伝わりにくいからこそ、わかりやすさが大事なんですよ。メタだとですけど。メタでない方は事実に基づくかどうかだけです。

Answer (score 7):

そうではないです。少なくとも主要な目的は違います。

#### このサイトの目的

このサイトの目的は、大きくは下の2つだと考えます。

- 「既成の解決方法のライブラリ」の蓄積
- 質問者が「現在抱える問題」の解決

（鉤かっこ内の語は[『コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観』](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values)より）

#### 自己顕示などは、サイトの目的の範囲に抑えるべき

自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たす目的で回答することは、まったく悪くないと思います (現在、それが叶うほどの活況は無いですが）。しかし、これらや親切心などの感情が上で述べたこのサイトの目的を害さぬように注意すべきです。例えば、

- 自分の著作や制作物の宣伝に終始する
- 自分の哲学や方法論の解説に終始する
- 質問内容よりも、質問者に対する指導に終始する
- 解決方法を知っていると仄めかしながら具体的には書かない
- 質問者と共有する文脈に依存し、第三者には読解が困難

といった回答は避けるべきです。もっとも、これらは程度問題であり、個別のケースを見ないと詳細には議論できないと思います。

Comment: 自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たす目的を肯定されてしまうと、回答者の保護が過ぎてしまいますね。また回答の前提となる知識の有無が不明な状態で、具体的な回答を書いてしまうことで、質問者の理解が進まない状況もよくないと思いますよ。

Comment: また質問者と共有する文脈に依存がよく分かりませんが、単純に読解が困難というのは単に理解力の不足か、純粋にその問題に慣れていない(言わずとしれた前提のような話の共有が出来ていない)だけの話かと思います。残念ながら限られた字数で全ての方の理解を最大まで引き上げるのは内容によっては困難となります。

Comment: @dameo 「質問者と共有する文脈」というのは、例えばですが、過去の質問やコメントのやりとりで得た情報です。
「単に理解力の不足」かどうかは、個別の事例ごとにしか判断できないと思います。

Comment: 解釈が1通りであり、内容が十分に記述されていれば、読解が困難に先に挙げた二通り以外がある気はしませんが・・・

Comment: 過去の質問やコメントのやり取りは参照されていれば十分でしょう。二重にあれば冗長になるだけですよ。

Comment: @dameo そうですね。「解釈が1通りであり、内容が十分に記述されていれば」私が挙げた「第三者には読解が困難」には該当しないですね。

Comment: では仮にその質問が
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92262/%e3%83%86%e3%82%ad%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e7%94%bb%e9%9d%a2%e3%82%92%e3%82%b3%e3%83%94%e3%83%bc%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6html%e3%81%a7%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84
であった場合、あなたの判断では「読解が困難」に該当するのでしょうか？

Comment: 「過去の質問やコメントのやり取りは参照されていれば十分」 → これも、十分に明確に参照されていれば、問題が無いでしょうね。（このサイトの事情としては、コメントは消えても良い類いに使う物なので、回答なり質問なりにまとめる必要が有りますが。）

Comment: 本文に反映されず無作為に削除されるコメントがあれば、経緯が分からなくなっても当然ですよね。ようは過去の質問にリンクされていれば十分ということですね。

Comment: @dameo 私はその質問（固定幅フォントの問題）に関しては瞬時に理解しました。
長年、付き合って来た問題ですので。
ただ、人によっては何を言っているのか解らないでしょうね。
画像が有れば誰にでも瞬時に伝わると思います。

Comment: @dameo 「過去の質問にリンクされていれば十分」かどうかは、事例によると思います。

Comment: 残念ながらそれでは質問の自由度が損なわれてしまいますし、何より質問に含まれる問題が私個人の認識に限定されてしまいます。あったほうが良いのではなく、あると問題なんですよ。もっと字数が入るなら話は別ですが。

Comment: 事例によるわけではありませんよ。ただの横暴な修正により、経緯が不明になっているだけです。

Comment: @dameo 「ただの横暴な修正により、経緯が不明になっている」とおっしゃっているのは、特定の質問の事ですよね？
全ての質問がそうなっている訳では無いのですから、やはり私としては「事例による」と考えます。

Comment: 文字通り(特定の)事例によらず、という意味ですが・・・

Comment: @dameo 「(特定の)事例によらず」の意味は理解しているつもりです。
理解した上で、「過去の質問にリンクされていれば十分」かどうかは事例による、というのが私の考えです。

Comment: ではどういう状況が考えられるのでしょうか？過去の質問のリンク以上に何かまとめ「ないといけない」状況とは・・・

Comment: @dameo さんにも 「長時間におよぶディスカッションをコメントで行うことは避けてください」というメッセージが出ている事と思います。これ以上は続けられません（私はチャットはしません）。
疑問点が有る場合は、別の質問として下さい。私のこの回答に反論が有る場合は、dameo さんの回答に含めるのも良いと思います。

Comment: メタな話だとこれは仕方ないことかと思いますよ。チャットがダメなら回答はやめたほうがいいです。

Comment: @dameo 確かに、StackOverflow の Q&A 形式は議論に適さない所が有ります。
しかし、長々とした二者間のチャットが有意義な議論になるかと言うと、またそれも微妙な所ですし、他の人は誰も読まないのが現実です。
私は、メタの議論も Q&A の形式で行う、という StackOverflow のシステムを妥協としてですが、受け入れて何とかやっていくつもりです。

Comment: 今やっていけないことが判明したばかりですよ。長々とした二者間のチャットで得られた結論のみを各位に展開するためのものだと理解しています。そもそもそれをしないつもりなら、回答すべきではありません。

Comment: @dameo 「そもそもそれをしないつもりなら、回答すべきではありません。」 → 例えばこの主張を、メタ質問として書かれてはいかがですか？ 私は反論を回答として書くでしょう。
そうやって議論が可能、というのが私の考えですし、このサイトにおける現実的な唯一の選択肢です。

Comment: そうやってチャット回避が可能とあなたが考えてるだけで、なぜチャットが必要なのかを考えてください。メタな議論というのには事実に基づく正解がないので、結論が簡単には出ないんですよ。長引く前提だからチャットがあるのにそれをしないから、却って余計な話をしようなんてことを言ってるだけですよ。

Answer (score 2):

> SO日本語版は回答者の自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たすためのサイトなのでしょうか？

いいえ違います。

> そうでなければ、その際に気をつけるべき点をご回答ください。

まぎれもなくSO日本語版はQ&Aサイトなのですから、Q; 質問 と A; 回答 の組が重要視されます。質問者は質問を書き、回答者は回答を書きます。裏返せば、質問者は質問に書かれていないことを回答者に要求してはいけません。しかし、逆は成立しません。Q&Aに役立つことであれば、回答者は質問に書かれていないことも回答することができます。

具体例をあげます。[質問者から次のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91776/stdmap%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E5%8C%96%E3%82%92%E7%B6%BA%E9%BA%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/91792?noredirect=1#comment105361_91792)が投稿されたことがあります。

> RVOは分かっていたのですが、コピー(/ムーブ)の省略が疑いない処理系ばかりでもないし、仮に最適化時だけ省略される処理系だと、最適化時処理が大きく変わることを良しとしないプロジェクトで意図的にmoveを使うことがあると思います。

しかし、質問文には**RVO / コピー / ムーブ**の話題も**処理系**の話題も触れられていません。ですので、質問者は回答内容としてこれらの話題を求めるべきではありません。もちろん、質問文に記載した上で回答内容として求めることには何ら問題はありません。

[同質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91776/4236)には

> ※C++17でお願いします

とあります。もちろん質問者としてはC++17という条件下での解決策を求めていることはわかります。しかし、質問者以外の閲覧者は必ずしもC++17という条件下で同等の問題に直面しているとは限りません。ですので、[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/91792/4236)のように

> C++20のstd::format()を使用できれば
> ...
> もっと簡単に済ませられます。

Q&Aとしては他の環境下での回答も有益と考えるべきです。

---

ところで、世界情勢として現在ウクライナとロシアが戦争状態にあり、ロシアは世界的に孤立状態にあります。こんな中、ロシアによる「ウクライナが～した」という発言のほとんどが、実際に実行したのはロシア自身ということがわかっています。一例をあげますと

- × ウクライナがロシアに先制攻撃を仕掛けたため、ロシアは防戦している。
- ○ ロシアがウクライナに先制攻撃を仕掛けたため、ウクライナは防戦している。

という具合です。dameoさんの投稿を見ていますと、現在のロシアと同じ印象を持ちます。つまり

- SO日本語版は回答者の自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たすためのサイトなのでしょうか？
  → 回答者が自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たそうとしているのではないか？
- dameoさんが自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たそうとしているのではないか？

一例をあげます。dameoさんは[このコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92395/udp%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%97%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/92401?noredirect=1#comment105309_92401)で

> 併記お願いできますか？

と回答内容の変更を要求しています。このコメントのみであれば問題ありません。しかし、[質問スレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/92395/4236)の全体を読むとわかりますが、何度も執拗にコメントをしたり、「回答ではありません」と称した投稿をし、さらにそのコメント欄でも一方的な主張を繰り返しています。

この質問スレッドを読むだけでもdameoさんが自己顕示欲や承認欲求を満たそうとしている印象を受けます。もちろん、他のスレッドでのやり取りも同様です。

ただ、ロシアと同様にdameoさんの行動は賛同を得られていません。dameoさんの投稿された質問および回答にはQ&Aとして中立的な評価がされいくつかのプラス投票がなされているものもあります。しかし、コメントは１つを除いてプラス投票がされていません（なお、コメントにはマイナス投票の機能はありません）。

- [UserId=54957 dameoさんの各投稿に対するスコア](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1676861)

dameoさんの（コメントでの）行動に対して、プラス投票しようと考える者がほぼ皆無であることを理解し、ご自身を省みることを望みます。

Comment: 「質問者は質問に書かれていないことを回答者に要求してはいけません」とありますが、
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91776/stdmap%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E5%8C%96%E3%82%92%E7%B6%BA%E9%BA%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/91792?noredirect=1#comment105383_91792 ですでにコメントしていますよ。
『私のコメントをよく読んで下さい。「正解を1つと考えていない」だけですよ。私の「綺麗」とあなたの「綺麗」、他の人の「綺麗」が違うだけです。全員の回答を見て、全員の「綺麗」が1つになるならそれが唯一の正解なだけです。主観的なのが問題なのは私の「綺麗」だけを唯一の正解とした場合ではないのですか？』

Comment: C++20は範囲外であり、C++17に限定できない話になるので、不要です。そもそも「簡単」の基準は人それぞれです。速度だって違うし、最適化頼みならその違いを気にする人もいるでしょう。明らかな事実でないことも指摘するという判断に至る理由になっています。

Comment: 自己顕示欲も承認欲求もありませんよ。単に回答者や質問者だけでないここに来た人全体の利益だけを考えています。併記をお願いしている理由は https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92395/udp%e3%82%bd%e3%82%b1%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%97%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%ae%e3%81%9f%e3%81%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bd%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84/92420#comment105379_92401 ですでに書いてますよね。
『…
例えばログ出力において最後が出力されないなどの現象に悩んでここに来た人が、対応方法を読んで、やってみたら超遅くなっちゃった、ということが考えられます。対策というのは影響範囲がなるべく少なくできた方がいいときも多いので、何度も言いますが、併記をお願いします。 – 
dameo
19 時間前  
godbolt.org/z/KahqrfKn5 多少意地悪な例ではありますが、こんな小さなサイズでも桁が違う時間の違いを生みますよ。 – 
dameo
18 時間前  』

Comment: 最後に、自分が付けていないスコアは嫌がらせと身内擁護だけだと思ってます。コメントまであれば、人による判断と理由などによる判断ができますが、そうじゃないので・・・