# 質問で「これまでに試したこと」の注意書きに「XY問題にならないようにしてください」と付け加えるべきではないですか？

Tags: 討議, 完了

質問を行なう際は「自分でどのような解決策を試みたか」も書くように指示されますが、疑問を丸投げするのではなく自分でどうすれば解決できるか考える善意（だが初心者）の質問者の場合、「自分の考えた解決案を実現できる方法」を質問してしまう、つまり[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e4%bd%95%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b)を投稿してしまうことがあるため、例えば「これまでに試したことを説明」の欄などに「ただし[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e4%bd%95%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b)にならないようにしてください」と注意書きを追記すべきではないでしょうか？
[image: 現在の質問する際の注意書き]

Comment: ただでさえ [stackoverflow は敷居が高くて投稿をためらっています] ような人が多いのに、さらに敷居を引き上げるのはどうなんかなーとか思ったりします。まあ追記するのは構わないでしょう。どうせ「質問の初心者」はそういうガイドラインなど読まないので。

Comment: @774RR 質問した後に「XY問題だ」と言われるよりは事前にその存在を知っておいたほうが良いでしょうし、「ただし、タイトルには自分の考えた解決案ではなく本来解決したい問題を書いてください。詳しくはこちら」ぐらいの追記ならそれほど負担にはならないかと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問のフローを改善していきたいという意味でむっちゃ良い提案だと思う一方で、あんまり凝りすぎると文章が長くなってしまうので、塩梅が難しいですね。

たとえば「1. 問題を要約する」の「目標を詳しく述べてください」を「もともと達成したかった目標について詳しく書いてください」にするのはどうでしょうか。

このくらいなら翻訳 string の https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12496 を書き換えれば変更できそうでした。

[image]

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ質問があるのですが、今後結論が出たとして、変更はどこ（誰）にお願いすればいいでしょう？ また、英語版についても同様の修正を動議したい場合どうすればいいでしょう？

Comment: 日本語版については、このまま少し待ってみて vote が集まって意見も出尽くしたようであれば、Traducir を変更するだけなのでそれができる人（モデレーターや翻訳ボランティア）が折を見て作業します（滞っていたらモデレーターにメンションをください）。英語版については、Stack Overflow のみについて提案したいのであればそのメタに、全サイトについて提案したいのであれば Meta Stack Exchange に提案することとなります。日本語版の方針とは別になります。

Comment: わかりました。Metaに関しては特に初心者なのでモデレーターの方々にお任せしたいと思います。

Comment: @lamrongol +5 votes 集まって、反対意見も特に無いようなので https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12496 を更新しました。1 週間以内くらいには翻訳が反映されるはずです〜。

Comment: 翻訳が反映されているのを確認しました。

Answer (score 2):

もし、XY問題について注意すべきとの指摘をするのであれば、その前の「問題を要約する」の所での「目標を詳しく述べてください」ではないのでしょうか？

XY問題の何が問題であるかというと、`X`が目標ではなく、`Y`が目標になってしまうことです。そのため、質問には「目標は`Y`です」と**だけ**書いてしまいます。つまり、XY問題であるかどうかを検討するのは、「試したこと」も書く前の「目標」を書く段階です。その「目標」がおかしいから、回答者まで混乱してしまったり、目標`Y`は解決できる「正しい回答」なのに、本当に解決したかった目標`X`は解決はできないという質問者だけが不満を持ってしまう事態が発生しまいます。

むしろ、正しく「目標」が設定されてさえいれば、試したことが全く見当違いであっても、その質問はXY問題ではないと思います。なぜなら、回答者は正しい目標を把握でき、その目標に向かった正しい回答をできるからです。「試したこと」は、本来は同じことが指摘させることを回避できるぐらいの役割でしか無く、副次的に、回答者の理解度の目安がわかる程度です。見当違いな内容であっても、「質問者は問題点の理解できていない、または、その部分に関する知識があまりないから、より詳しく、丁寧に解説しよう」ということを回答者が思う程度で、むしろ質問者にとってもプラスに働くとも思います。よって、試したことによって、XY問題になってしまうという懸念はないかと思います。

ただ、XY問題について言及するのは必要性はそれほど無いとも思っています。なぜなら、XY問題に陥っている質問者の多くはXY問題だと言うこと自体に自分では気づけない状態に嵌まって締まっているからです。もし、XY問題に言及するのであれば「良い質問をするには？」の項目のトピックとしてあげるぐらいでいいかと思います。

Comment: "例えば「これまでに試したことを説明」の欄など"と書いたようにあくまで例示の一つなので、別の適切な場所があるということならそこにXY問題への言及を書くべきだとは思います。XY問題を投稿してしまう人（私自身投稿したことがありますが）も「XY問題」という概念を知れば、自分が投稿しようとしている内容がXY問題かどうか気付けると思います。